# Monotony for a not derivable function by parts

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

Let $f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{(e^{x^2}-5x^2-2)}{x^2}, \quad x\neq 0 \\
0                             , \quad x=0
\end{cases}$
This is not a derivable function in fact it is not continous since $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(e^{x^2}-5x^2-2)}{x^2}\neq 0$. So since I can't use the first derivative if I want to study if it is increasing (strictly) or decreasing how can I do?

Comment: try big-O notation.

Comment: I don't know the big-O notation, can you give me another way to solve it?

Comment: that's a basic skill in graduate studies.  see the "post-rigorous stage" in Terence Tao's article: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/theres-more-to-mathematics-than-rigour-and-proofs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ does not mean that it is not differentiable on its entire domain. In particular, we can differentiate $f(x)$ to get $$f'(x)=\frac{(2x^2-2)e^{x^2}+4}{x^3}$$
and we can easily see that $f'(x)<0$ for $x<0$ and $f'(x)>0$ for $x>0$, i.e. it is strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$ and strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$.

We get the same conclusion with a graph:

[image]

Comment: Really the exercise tell me to prove the strictly monotony on $\mathbb{R}$, what's about 0?

Comment: @Nik edited my answer with a graph, which shows that the function is not strictly monotone on $\mathbb R$

Comment: Ok thanks! If my function for instance was with first derivative >0 $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ but the function in x=0 it is defined 0 (like in the exercise above) how I can conclude the strictly monotony?

Comment: in this case you can show that the left-hand limit at $x=0$ is smaller than $0$, while the right-hand limit at $x=0$ is greater than $0$

Comment: The limit of the derivative?

Comment: The limit of the function

Comment: Otherwise if after proving that the first derivative of not null branch is positive, if I prove that the this branch of my function is >0 for x>0 and <0 for x<0 it is correct?

Comment: @Nik that's right as well

Comment: Thanks a lot for all explanations!